# C# List property unresponsive to adding new elements

Tags: c#, list, properties

Would you help me understand why before exiting the Main function the repository.Courses is null, even though I had just added a course to the repository by calling  `repository.AddCourse(course);` before exiting? How would I correct this? I think it may have to do with how the Courses property is defined (getter and setter). In teh getter I want to initialize by an empty list only if it's already null, otherwise I want to return the existing list. In the setter I want to assign a value - this should be correlated with the possibility of adding to list.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{

    class Repo
    {

        public IList<Course> _courses;

        public IList<Course> Courses
        {
            get
            {
                if (_courses == null)
                    _courses = new List<Course>();
                return new List<Course>(_courses);
            }
            set
            {
                _courses = value;

            }
        }
        public void AddCourse(Course course)
        {
            course.Id = Courses.NextId();
            Courses.Add(course);
        }


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Repo repository = new Repo();
            var path = "C:\\a1\\demos\\demo1-after\\ConsoleApplication1\\json1.json";
            var reader = new StreamReader(path);

            string text = reader.ReadToEnd();
            var course = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Course>(text);
            repository.AddCourse(course);

        }
    }

    public class Course : IEntity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Author { get; set; }
        public Course(string n, string a)
        {
            Name = n;
            Author = a;

        }
    }

    public interface IEntity
    {
        int Id { get; set; }
    }
    public static class Extensions
    {
        public static int NextId<T>(this IList<T> list) where T : IEntity
        {
            return list.Any() ? list.Max(x => x.Id) + 1 : 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `return new List<Course>(_courses);` in the `get` **always** returns a new list and `Courses.Add` does not call `set`.

Comment: You should return the current list (`_courses`) as @crashmstr says instead of a new list.

Comment: Simpler version: `public IList<Course> Courses { get; set; } = new List<Course>();` (you then don't need the backing variable, and lazy creation of the empty list does not give you much here).

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that your `get` is always returning a *new* list, rather than the backing field.

Try this instead:

```
get
{
    if (_courses == null) _courses = new List<Course>();
    return _courses;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that the getter of Courses returns a new list rather than a reference to the field. Is that because you don't want anyone from outside the class to be able to add anything to the list except through AddCourse?
In this case the fix I'd recommend is to change AddCourse to address the field directly rather than the property, as currently it's adding the item to the new list created by the getter rather than to the list referenced by your field.